# stringWithContentsOfURL returning (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I'm trying to convert a URL to a String with the following code:

```
NSURL *urlOfOpenedFile = _service.myURLRequest.URL;
NSString *fileThatWasOpened = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlOfOpenedFile encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"url: %@", urlOfOpenedFile);
NSLog(@"string: %@", fileThatWasOpened);
```

This returns:

```
url: file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%2520Support/iPhone%2520Simulator/6.0/Applications/72AA03A1-3967-4F22-9745-0722C8DE9FAC/Documents/downloads/My%20Document%20.pdf
string: (null)
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert the URL to a string? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like

`NSString *fileThatWasOpened = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
NSString* yourURLString = [urlOfOpenedFile absoluteString];
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you use is not for converting a NSURL to a NSString. Instead like the method name it returns the string from content of that URL. Since you have PDF file (not string) on that URL it returns nil.

For converting you can use the following instance method of NSURL

`- (NSString *)absoluteString;`